# How does queue front and back referencing work?

Tags: python, queue, singly-linked-list

In my CS1 class, we are currently learning about singly-linked lists, stacks, and queues in python. We were doing an example of adding a new element to a queue and setting the queue's front and back references to accordingly. I do not understand why I get this particular output. When `queue.back.next = new_part` is executed, it should only change `queue.back.next` to `the new_part` node, yet it changes both `queue.front.next` and `queue.back.next` to equal `new_part`. Why is this happening?

I have tried debugging, and stepping through each line. When I get to line 7 (the line mentioned) in my execution, it just sets both `queue.front.next` and `queue.back.next` to `new_part`.

enqueue function:

```py
def enqueue(queue, element):
    new_part = Node(element, None)
    if is_empty_queue(queue):
        queue.front = new_part
    else:
        queue.back.next = new_part
    queue.back = new_part
```

test function:

```py
def test_enqueue():
    new_queue = make_queue()
    enqueue(new_queue, 'arms')
    print(new_queue)
    enqueue(new_queue, 'legs')
    print(new_queue)
    enqueue(new_queue, 'head')
    print(new_queue)
```

output

```
Queue(size=0, front=Node(value='arms', next=None), back=Node(value='arms', next=None))
Queue(size=0, front=Node(value='arms', next=Node(value='legs', next=None)), back=Node(value='legs', next=None))
Queue(size=0, front=Node(value='arms', next=Node(value='legs', next=Node(value='head', next=None))), back=Node(value='head', next=None))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is what you want (except that you need to add the logic to track the queue size properly): after enqueueing the three elements, the `'arms'` one is at the front of the queue, and the `'head'` one is at the back. So I assume the question is just about understanding the code, rather than fixing it.

> `queue.back.next = new_part` is executed, it should only change `queue.back.next` to the new_part node, yet it changes both `queue.front.next` and `queue.back.next` to equal new_part. Why is this happening?

When the *first* element is enqueued, `queue.front = new_part` and `queue.back = new_part` are both executed, making them both refer to the newly created `new_part = Node(element, None)`. Therefore, immediately before enqueuing the *second* element, `queue.front` and `queue.back` *are the same object*.

This is in fact correct behaviour; logically, for a queue that has one element in it, the front and back are indeed the same item. So when the second element is added, it should be the `next` of what was previously the front of the queue, and also the `next` of what was previously the back of the queue. So we make that link, and then re-adjust `queue.back` to refer to the new element, since it is now the back of the queue.

As you can see when enqueuing the third element, the `queue.front` and `queue.back` are no longer the same to start with, and thus `queue.front` is not affected.